# Non-Deterministic Push Down Automata

Tags: automata

Can we make a NPDA for the following language?

$$L=\big\{w\in\{a,b\}^*:|w|_a\ne 3|w|_b\big\}$$

I was asked this question in exam today and I was unable to do so. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: The language satisfying $|w_a| = |w_b|$ is deterministic context free and hence its complement is too. Can you modify this to deal with $L$ above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A language is context free **iff** there is a NPDA that accepts it.

\begin{eqnarray}
M &\to& \epsilon\\
&\to& M a M aMaMbM \\
&\to& M a M aMbMaM \\
&\to& M a M bMaMaM \\
&\to& M b M aMaMaM \\
\\
A &\to& a | M A M\\
\\
B &\to& b | M B M \\
\\
S &\to& A | B  \\
\end{eqnarray}
Any string $w$ derived from $M$ satisfies $|w|_a = 3 |w|_b$, and similarly,
any string satisfying $|w|_a = 3 |w|_b$ can be derived from $M$.

Any string derived from $A$ has an excess of $a$s, and similarly,
any string with an excess of $a$s can be derived from $A$. Similarly
for $B$.

Hence the strings derived from $S$ are the same as the language $L$.